# Hash for lambda function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, lambda

I'm trying to get the hash of a lambda function. Why do I get two values (8746164008739 and -9223363290690767077)? Why is the hash from the lambda function not always one value?

```
>>> fn = lambda: 1
>>> hash(fn)
-9223363290690767077
>>> fn = lambda: 1
>>> hash(fn)
8746164008739
>>> fn = lambda: 1
>>> hash(fn)
-9223363290690767077
>>> fn = lambda: 1
>>> hash(fn)
8746164008739
>>> fn = lambda: 1
>>> hash(fn)
-9223363290690767077
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you do realise that you're hashing the actual function object itself, you're not hashing the value that it would return when called, right?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea, but you could just consider the code object: `hash((lambda : 1).__code__)`

Comment: just curious... what use models would you need this functionality for? do you commonly look up things in dictionaries based on an arbitrary function?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I can imagine having a `set()` of callbacks and wanting it not to keep the same callback twice.

Comment: Another case would be persistent memoization - suppose you want to save the result of a long-running function for a given input to disk so that you can retrieve it later, you may use the hash of the function code and its inputs to reference the saved result.  But as has been mentioned, you really have to also hash all globals and called functions to do this perfectly.

Answer (score 43):

Two objects are not guaranteed to hash to the same value unless they compare equal [1].

Python functions (including lambdas) don't compare equal even if they have identical code [2]. For example:

```
>>> (lambda: 1) == (lambda: 1)
False
```

Implementation-wise, this behaviour is due to the fact that function objects don't provide their own equality operator. Instead, they inherit the default one that uses the object's identity, i.e. its address. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__):

> If no `__cmp__()`, `__eq__()` or `__ne__()` operation is defined, class
>   instances are compared by object identity (“address”).

Here is what happens in your particular example:

```
fn = lambda: 1  # New function is allocated at address A and stored in fn.
fn = lambda: 1  # New function is allocated at address B and stored in fn.
                # The function at address A is garbage collected.
fn = lambda: 1  # New function is allocated at address A and stored in fn.
                # The function at address B is garbage collected.
fn = lambda: 1  # New function is allocated at address B and stored in fn.
                # The function at address A is garbage collected.
...
```

Since address `A` is always hashed to one value, and address `B` to another, you are seeing `hash(fn)` alternate between the two values. This alternating behaviour is, however, an implementation artefact and could change one day if, for example, the garbage collector were made to behave slightly differently.

The following insightful note has been contributed by @ruakh:

> It is worth noting that it's not possible to write a general process
>   for determining if two functions are equivalent. (This is a
>   consequence of the [undecidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).)
>   Furthermore, two Python functions can behave differently even if their
>   code is identical (since they may be closures referring to
>   distinct-but-identically-named variables). So it makes sense that
>   Python functions don't overload the equality operator: there's no way
>   to implement anything better than the default object-identity
>   comparison.

[1] The converse is generally not true: two objects that compare unequal can have the same hash value. This is called a [hash collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science)).

[2] *Calling* your lambdas and then hashing the result would of course always give the same value since `hash(1)` is always the same within one program:

```
>>> (lambda: 1)() == (lambda: 1)()
True
```

Comment: About the first sentence, don't objects compare equal *if* their hashes are equal ?

Comment: @muraveill: No, there could be a hash collision.

Comment: @muraveill The confusion about that might be due to the phrasing.  The phrasing is correct, but the phrasing may make more sense as part of a compound statement: "If two objects are equal, then their hashes are guaranteed to be equal (by the specification of `hash()`).  If two objects are not equal, then their hashes may or may not be equal."

Comment: +1. It may also be worth pointing out that it's not possible to write a general process for determining if two functions are equivalent. (This is a consequence of the undecidability of the halting problem.) Furthermore, two Python functions can behave differently even if their code is identical (since they may be closures referring to distinct-but-identically-named variables). So it makes sense that Python functions don't overload the equality operator: there's no way to implement anything better than the default object-identity comparison.

Comment: @ruakh Indeed, and in fact in functional languages like Standard ML or Haskell (which don't subscribe to the notion that everything is a pointer to an object) functions don't have an equality operator at all.

Comment: @ruakh: This is very insightful, thanks! I'll add your note to the answer verbatim (with attribution).

Answer (score 10):

The hash of a `lambda` function object is based on its memory address (in CPython this is what the `id` function returns). This means that any two function objects will have different hashes (assuming there are no hash collisions), even if the functions contain the same code.

To explain what's happening in the question, first note that writing `fn = lambda: 1` creates a new function object in memory and binds the name `fn` to it. This new function will therefore have a different hash value to any existing functions.

Repeating `fn = lambda: 1`, you get alternating values for the hashes because when `fn` is bound to the *newly* created function object, the function that `fn` *previously* pointed to is garbage collected by Python. This is because there are no longer any references to it (since the name `fn` now points to a different object).

The Python interpreter then reuses this old memory address for the next new function object created by writing `fn = lambda: 1`.

This behaviour might vary between different systems and Python implementations.

Answer (score 5):

Each time you do `fn = lambda: 1` a new function object is created, and the old object bound to the name `fn` is marked for deletion. But Python doesn't simply deallocate the object, passing its memory back to the OS. To minimize system calls for memory allocation and to minimize memory fragmentation Python tries to recycle memory when it can. And so when you create `fn = lambda: 1` a third time the interpreter notices it's got a block of RAM handy that's big enough for the new function object, and so it uses that block. And thus your 3rd `fn` ends up in that block of RAM and hence has the same id as the first `fn`, since the id of CPython objects is their memory address.

(As others have mentioned the hash of any object type that doesn't provide a specific implementation of `__hash__` is based on its id in CPython. And if a class does not define a `__cmp__` or `__eq__` method it should not define a `__hash__` operation either).

Answer (score 5):

Deciding whether two functions are equal is impossible, as it is a superset of the halting problem.

In an ideal world, comparing (and therefore hashing) functions would result in a type error. Python apparently doesn't like this, and instead chooses to use the identity of the functions to compare (and therefore hash) them.

Comment: two functions that always produce the same value are not equivalent, for most purposes of equivalence of lambdas.   it would be more than sufficient to compare bytecode for the use case proposed by the o/p

Answer (score 0):

Implementation-dependent way to get reasonably sufficient contents of a lambda in python3:

```
def function_contents(func):
    closure = tuple(cell.cell_contents for cell in func.__closure__) if func.__closure__ else ()
    return (func.__name__, func.__defaults__, closure, func.__code__.co_code, func.__code__.co_consts)
```

This includes:

- the code of the lambda
- default captures
- closure captures

Should be enough for your use case.

Your example:

```
fn = lambda: 1
hash(function_contents(fn))
fn = lambda: 1
hash(function_contents(fn))
fn = lambda: 1
hash(function_contents(fn))
```

... same value every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash_func = lambda input_str: hashlib.sha256(input_str.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.